# Does the HP DL20 gen10 support video redirection at all times with an advanced iLO license

Tags: hp, ilo, video, keyboard-video-mouse

We recently bought an HP DL20 gen10 through a reseller and it is missing the hardware iLO NIC.  The HP quicksheet now shows iLO as an optional component despite us having bought the advanced iLO license.  We're working with the reseller to sort this out.

In the meantime and doing more research, this article:

https://www.servethehome.com/hpe-proliant-dl20-gen10-review-compact-and-nimble-server/2/

seems to suggest that video redirection (now iKVM?) is only available at post or boot.  I've never heard of this even for lowly 1U servers years ago (iLO or DRAC).

Is anyone able to verify a potential limited video redirection for lower end HP servers?

Answer (score 3):

I shouldn't give this advice...

The ILO standard will show the POST and BIOS video output up until the IOS begins to boot. You need the ILO license to see more.

You can obtain an [ILO trial license here](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/resources/integrated-systems/ilo-advanced-trial.html).

You can buy an inexpensive ILO license on [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-HP-iLO-Advanced-License-iLO-3-iLO-4-iLO-5-ALL-HPE-SERVERS-FAST-SHIP/173890593721?_trkparms=ispr%3D1&hash=item287cafe3b9:g:msIAAOSw3ChbNgFY&enc=AQAEAAAB0BPxNw%2BVj6nta7CKEs3N0qVmHl5jiC0Ce6A%2FKQThg%2Bd1S6zoOkmO1lu8IL%2FdI9uStZPwVMXAHkpWUfXJmEeCXmHGrPlPOn2EIvaOoxV3p63JaOSIHh3T3ydRxje%2FQg607lLLX%2F93CDEZm9o1%2FkmECNm4nPbaOe7lvYQfOHpWCj1L4PZpdT4d6QkXkM2Z0EEsqSt1BoTcpkaqD8tF6kSIFNM4lj3dDSgBEx8NfN%2F04aj6qR5qUZXt7atCO7Arl64dvg4QL9%2BFa908eYVSZszH3RlKmtOt6I3RjixvWQ2LGSyD%2Fyf2fUR4u9rE6ofqOT882onP1%2BmdiqKBxZz4SvXni69jd4HeXdLg0RlBsKuEzhHwVnBYDrc2jLdnNHkWVpshWkQja4dsjODxOW54GttLk7ZFPc2KvJ2C16pJJybrd8ituBMRf1%2FfCMUc0631gw5mwap4Tp4Unhr9vEbBZ7Uf9NUnq45j%2FizILpFxEz%2FwIZIszdxtzUqugpUKCsm3IfI0sg1eX7nMXpeqbeRNXQpUFYbgw4kKWsr2cJ%2BpN8ivyopi65rQN9x6eYCrrKt%2FWbUlbbIHa7%2F064yHc9dP9ryhGpzgxmPDtDjogBsItok0bJiY&checksum=17389059372119354b1679fb4439a741412966da7e7a) or through your reseller, or search *very* carefully on the web.

Try the trial, see if it works and go from there.

For the ILO port, it's not really necessary to have a dedicated hardware port. Right now, it's shared with the first NIC.

Comment: We already have an advanced iLO license purchased.  I'm wondering if the DL20 line of servers is the exception to what most would expect out of video redirection.

Comment: No. It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Verified by hand, the iLO on this lower tier of servers does in-fact allow video redirection at all times with an advanced iLO license.  Some of the language in the posted review link is ambiguous.